# Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in BMI Calculator

Tags: php

I tried to make BMI Calculator using php where the student is needed to input their names, matric number, height and weight to know their BMI.

However ,I got this error
**Fatal error: Uncaught Division By Zero Error: Division by zero**

but it disappeared when I put the value inside.
I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

HMTL Form

```
    <form>
        Enter your name : <input type = "text" name = "student_name" value = "<?php echo @$_GET["student_name"]?>">  <!--Accepts name-->
        <br>
        Enter matric number : <input type = "text" name = "student_matricno" value = "<?php echo @$_GET["student_matricno"]?>"> <!--Accepts Matric Number-->
        <br>
        Enter weight (in KG): <input type ="text" name = "student_weight" value = "<?php echo @$_GET["student_weight"]?>"> <!--Accepts student's weight-->
        <br>
        Enter Height (in Meters): <input type ="text" name = "student_height" value = "<?php echo @$_GET["student_height"]?>"> <!--Accepts student's height-->
        <br>
        <input type = "submit">

    </form>
          

   <table> <!--Create table and display the values inputted by the user-->
        <tr>
            <th colspan ="2">Student Information</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><?php echo @$_GET["student_name"]?></td>     
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td>Matric Number</td>
            <td><?php echo @$_GET["student_matricno"]?></td>  
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td><?php echo @$_GET["student_weight"]?> kg</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td><?php echo @$_GET["student_height"]?> meters</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

PHP code

````
 
 $weight = @$_GET["student_weight"];  
 $height = @$_GET["student_height"];
 
 function myBMI($weight,$height)  //function to calculate BMI
 {       $BMI = 0;
         $BMI = $weight / ($height * $height);
         return $BMI;
 }
 
 $BodyMassIndex = number_format(myBMI($weight,$height),2); //convert the calculated values into 2 decimal places
 
     //conditions for BMI
     if ($BodyMassIndex < 18.5)   
     {
         $status = "Underweight";
     }
     else if($BodyMassIndex < 21)
     {
         $status = "Normal";
     }
     else if($BodyMassIndex < 26)
     {
         $status = "Overweight";
     }
     else
     {
         $status = "OBESE";
     }

echo "My BMI is" .$BodyMassIndex. "and I am ".$status;
 ?>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The function does no sanity checks on the input values supplied. In the below a very simple test is done to ensure that neither value is zero (empty) and will print an alternative message if this is so. Using an `elvis` operator when assigning the values to `$height` & `$weight` sets them at zero if they are not present in the GET request at that stage which ensures a zero value is passed to the function.

```
<?php

    $weight = $_GET["student_weight"] ?: 0;  
    $height = $_GET["student_height"] ?: 0;

    function myBMI( $weight=0,$height=0 ){
        return !empty($weight) && !empty( $height ) ?  $weight / ( $height * $height ) : 0;
    }

    $BodyMassIndex = number_format( myBMI( $weight, $height ),2 );


    if ($BodyMassIndex < 18.5) {
        $status = "Underweight";
    }else if($BodyMassIndex < 21){
        $status = "Normal";
    }else if($BodyMassIndex < 26){
        $status = "Overweight";
    }else{
        $status = "OBESE";
    }
    
    if( $BodyMassIndex > 0 ) echo "My BMI is" .$BodyMassIndex. "and I am ".$status;
    else echo "<span style='color:red'>Please fully complete the form to calculate your BMI</span>";
?>
```